# Add Space Before Last Character in Variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, variable

I have a variable that contains some numbers then a letter

example: 242M

I need to add a space right before the last character in that variable so that when echo'd it would look like 242 M

I've tried sed but it looks like from what I can find that only works with reading from a file and I haven't been able to get this to work modifying a variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version that should work on any POSIX shell, not just `bash`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${a%?} ${a#"${a%?}"}"
```

The extra quotes inside `${a#...}` are to protect against special characters from the variable:

```
$ a='10*M'; printf '%s\n' "${a%?} ${a#"${a%?}"}"
10* M
```

Without them, the second variable expansion would've turned into `${a#10*}`, and `10* *M` would've been echoed instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answer doesn't work (e.g. on macOS), you can also try

```
a="${a%?} ${a: -1}"
```

which puts together *a without its last character*, a space, and *the last character of a*.

Answer (score 0):

Purely within the shell:

```
var=${var:0:-1}' '${var: -1:1}
```

For example:

```
$ var=jeff
$ var=${var:0:-1}' '${var: -1:1}
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
jef f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sed example that works with a variable:

```
q=242M
sed 's/.$/ &/' <<eof
$q
eof
```